# datatable plugin not display elements after clicking again on link to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using data table plugin for table pagination, it work for the first time, but when I click again on link to show the table all elements of data table plugin disappears, do you know how to solve this problem. thanks.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">    
      <div class="row content">
       <div class="col-lg-2 sidenav">
      <a href="#" id="link3" class="list-group-item">Vertical link #3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 text-left"> 
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12" id="content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- link3 -->
<script src="link3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

link3.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Position</th><th>Note</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>').addClass('table table-bordered table-hover search-table');
    $("#link3").on("click", function () {
      $('#content').html(table);
    $.ajax({
        url:'test.json',
        dataType:'json',
        type:'GET',
        Accept:"aplication/json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                var id = item.name;
                var id2= item.age;
                var id3=item.position;
                var id4=item.note;
                $(".table").append("<tr><td>"+id+"</td><td>"+id2+"</td><td>"+id3+"</td><td>"+id4+"</td></tr>");
            });
            $('.search-table').DataTable();
        },
        error:function(e){
            alert("there is some thing wrong!")
        }
    });
});

});
```

test.json

```
[

  {
    "name": "Olivia Doe",
    "age": "18",
    "position": "SW developer",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Sophia Doe",
    "age": "19",
    "position": "Graphic",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Ava Doe",
    "age": "20",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Joshua Doe",
    "age": "21",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Viktor Doe",
    "age": "22",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Ahmed Doe",
    "age": "23",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Emma Doe",
    "age": "24",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Evelyn Doe",
    "age": "25",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": "Evelyn's work is always amazing!"
  },
  {
    "name": "Noah Doe",
    "age": "26",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Liam Doe",
    "age": "27",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mason Doe",
    "age": "28",
    "position": "Analyst",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Jacob Doe",
    "age": "29",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "William Doe",
    "age": "30",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Ethan Doe",
    "age": "18",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": "Great job Ethan\nas always!"
  },
  {
    "name": "James Doe",
    "age": "20",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Alexander Doe",
    "age": "21",
    "position": "Project manager",
    "note": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).ready(function() {
            var data = [];
            data.push(
                [1,"Sasha","Brenna","0800 1111"],
                [2,"Sage","Mia","(01012) 405872"],
                [3,"Chelsea","Allistair","076 0578 0265"],
                [4,"Uta","Savannah","070 1247 5884"],
                [5,"Remedios","Berk","0995 181 0007"],
                [6,"Ruby","Wayne","0800 1111"],
                [7,"Faith","Fredericka","(01709) 099879"],
                [8,"Myra","Harrison","070 4241 9576"],
                [9,"Drake","Miriam","0800 733635"],
                [10,"Reed","Shannon","076 8597 5067"],
                [11,"Sasha","Brenna","0800 1111"],
                [12,"Sage","Mia","(01012) 405872"],
                [13,"Chelsea","Allistair","076 0578 0265"],
                [14,"Uta","Savannah","070 1247 5884"],
                [15,"Remedios","Berk","0995 181 0007"],
                [16,"Ruby","Wayne","0800 1111"],
                [17,"Faith","Fredericka","(01709) 099879"],
                [18,"Myra","Harrison","070 4241 9576"],
                [19,"Drake","Miriam","0800 733635"],
                [20,"Reed","Shannon","076 8597 5067"]
            );

            $('#data_table').DataTable( {
                data: data,
            });
        });
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cubttgow/18/)

Comment: it seems ok but i have to get the table data from json file

Comment: You can, just replace the static data to the json file data read through ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your json from url directly to datatable using `url` and `datasource` attribute, [refer](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax)

You can write your code

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: 'test.json',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "age" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "note" }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: can you please tell me in my case what should write in dataSrc: ' ' and columns: [ ... ]. thanks

Comment: dataSrc should be blank and updated columns in answer, you can also refer https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html for columns

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below Code It will directly add JSON to data table:
 
$('.search-table').DataTable({"ajax": "test.json"});
Take Reference from https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: I have try it but still  can not load the JSON

Comment: Change your JSON format to Like below:
[

  [
     "Olivia Doe",
     "18",
     "SW developer",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Sophia Doe",
     "19",
     "Graphic",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Ava Doe",
     "20",
     "Project manager",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Joshua Doe",
     "21",
     "Analyst",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Viktor Doe",
     "22",
     "Analyst",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Ahmed Doe",
     "23",
     "Analyst",
     ""
  ],
  [
     "Emma Doe",
     "24",
     "Analyst",
     ""
  ],

]

Comment: The Above data format i have seen in https://datatables.net/manual/data/

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({"sAjaxSource" : "Your_url"});
```

Provide the url that returns your jsondata.